# How to block Windows application request in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have an asp.net mvc and a windows application.
that use web client to connect to ASP.Net mvc
i want block request from windows application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that Google Chrome,IE,Forefox and all the other browsers are also windows applications which we use to access websites.If you want to block access to a specific browser\user againt you can create an MVC filter and inspect the following `HttpContext` properties:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserAgent;
//Returns something like - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
```

**OR**

```
string browser = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Browser.Browser;
//Returns something like - Chrome
```

Create the following filter, identify what the user agent is when you call the website from your windows application and put in logic which will re-direct the user if the specific user agent is encountered or throw an Unauthorized HTTP status code:

```
public class CallerInterceptorAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string userAgent = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserAgent;
        string browser = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Browser.Browser;

        if (browser == "Chrome")
        {
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com", true);
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

The action filter above can be applied at controller level,action or global to the whole application:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [CallerInterceptorAttribute]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: when i checked `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserAgent;` this code with **Microsoft Edge** it returns as **Chrome**